# How to make_shared a derived class?

Tags: c++, c++11, memory-management, stl, smart-pointers

I want to use the `make_shared<T>` function with a derived class, like below

```
class Base {
     public:
     typedef std::shared_ptr<Base> Ptr;
};

class Derived : public Base {};

Base::Ptr myPtr = std::make_shared(/* Derived() */ );
```

How can I tell make_shared to build such an object?

I want to avoid the classical

```
Base::Ptr ptr = Base::Ptr(new Derived());
```

To make use of the single alloc in the make_shared function.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

`std::shared_ptr` has a converting constructor that can make a `shared_ptr<Base>` from a `shared_ptr<Derived>`, so the following should work:

```
#include <memory>
class Base {
    public:
    typedef std::shared_ptr<Base> Ptr;
};
class Derived : public Base {};

int main() {
    Base::Ptr myPtr = std::make_shared<Derived>();
}
```